# Как правильно написать символ

Tags: javascript

[image: Стрелочка в коде]

Как правильно написать такую стрелку, если пишу двумя символами => , то выдает ошибку.

мой код:

```
export default { data() => ({ displayDays: 0, displayHours: 0, displayMinutes: 0, displaySeconds: 0 }) };
```

Comment: какую ошибку выдаёт? Приведите полный код

Comment: Может ваша IDE заменяет как-то символы (аля как Word тире на большое тире заменяет)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
export default { data: () => ({ displayDays: 0, displayHours: 0, displayMinutes: 0, displaySeconds: 0 }) };
```

Comment: пожалуйста, оставляйте чуть более развёрнутые ответы. [постарайтесь рассказать обо всех нюансах, которые могут возникнуть при решении проблемы по вашему сценарию. изложите свои предложения. возможен и краткий ответ, но чем подробнее и понятнее он будет изложен, тем лучше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Answer (score 0):

Писать надо: слитно символ "равно" и символ "больше чем"

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

Попробуйте так:

```
export default { data = () => ({ displayDays: 0, displayHours: 0, displayMinutes: 0, displaySeconds: 0 }) };
```

Похоже вы знак равно забыли:

```
data = () =>
```

или двоеточие:

```
data : () =>
```

Comment: я написала что пишу двумя такими символами и выдает ошибку. Может это другая стрелка какая то и по другому пишется

Comment: @Дарья покажите свой код и и покажите текст ошибки

Comment: @Дарья какими такими и как двумя? типа `= = >` только без пробелов? То это не верная записать)

Comment: <script>
export default {
  data() => ({
    displayDays: 0,
    displayHours: 0,
    displayMinutes: 0,
    displaySeconds: 0
  })
  
};
</script>

Comment: @Дарья а текст ошибки?

Comment: @Дарья пробуйте так: `export default { data = () => ({ displayDays: 0, displayHours: 0, displayMinutes: 0, displaySeconds: 0 }) }; ` --- похоже вы знак равно забыли `data = () =>`

Comment: нет, там не должно быть равно.

Comment: @Дарья да, на экспорт не посмотрел.. значит двоеточие `data : () =>` - добавил в ответ

Comment: вот теперь все ок)

Comment: @Дарья Пожалуйста! :) Галочка слева от ответа - тык)